# Quickest way to validate form input fields with JS

Tags: forms, validation, field

What is the quickest way to validate al my input fields with javaScript?
I want to check if the fields are filled in or not.

Thx

Comment: Please be more specific, in general jQuery has a nice validation plugin and also html5 does a lot of client side validation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following is my javascript code :

```
<script>
function Check(frm) 
{
  var input, EmptyFound=false; 
  var elem = document.getElementById('frmMain').elements;
  for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) 
  {
    input = elem[i];
    if(input.type == "text") 
    {
        if(input.value == "") 
       {
            EmptyFound = true;
            break; 
        }
    }

    return notEmpty; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to validate only inputs of type "text" and "password"?EDIT: it's allready in your answer :)

Comment: Check for type == "text" || type == "password" in the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

> A single line of jQuery to select the form and apply the validation
>   plugin. And a bit of metadata on each element to specify the
>   validation rules.

The docs specifically for enforcing required are at

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required

It requires adding jQuery (if you don't use it already) but provides a fast and powerful validation framework.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this to distinguish between input different types**

this is just a sample from my project

```
    //var frm_elements = document.mainForm.elements;
    //var frm_elements =document.getElementById('mainForm').elements;

    for (var i = 0; i < document.mainForm.elements.length; i++)
    {document.mainForm.elements[i];
        if(document.mainForm.elements[i]!=null)

        {

            var field_type = document.mainForm.elements[i].type;
            switch (field_type)
            {
                case "text":
                    if(document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("from")!='-1' &&
                        document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("frotom")!='-1' &&
                        !document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("serNo")!='-1' &&
                        !document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("repKey")!='-1' &&
                        !document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("orderKey")!='-1' &&
                        !document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("formatKey")!='-1' )
                    {
                        document.mainForm.elements[i].value = "";
                    }

                    break;
                case "password":
                case "textarea":
                case "hidden":
                /* frm_elements[i].value = "";
                    break;*/
            case "radio":
            case "checkbox":
            /*if (frm_elements[i].checked)
                    {
                        frm_elements[i].checked = false;
                    }
                    break;*/
        case "select-one":
        case "select-multi":
            if(document.mainForm.elements[i].name.indexOf("ddlMainSubModule")=='-1')
                document.mainForm.elements[i].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}